# Tensorflow: Identifying the operation in a custom-loss function that does not have a gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to create a custom loss function in Tensorflow. The network has the purpose of getting two images as the input and outputting a number which predicts the angular difference between the two images. Therefore my custom loss function has to rotate one image according to the number from the output and compare the rotated image to the other image.

This is what I wrote for the loss function:

```
def test_custom_loss_function(y_true, y_pred):

y_true=K.cast(y_true, dtype='float32')
y_pred=K.cast(y_pred, dtype='float32')

fixed_filtered = tfa.image.median_filter2d(y_true[0,:,:])
moving_filtered = tfa.image.median_filter2d(y_true[1,:,:])

fixed_filtered=K.cast(fixed_filtered, dtype='float32')
moving_filtered=K.cast(moving_filtered, dtype='float32')

fixed_mask = tf.where(tf.math.less(tf.constant([20.0]), fixed_filtered),1.0,0.0)
moving_mask = tf.where(tf.math.less(tf.constant([20.0]), moving_filtered),1.0,0.0)

fixed_mask_r = tfa.image.rotate(fixed_mask, tf.constant(0.0))
moving_mask_r = tfa.image.rotate(moving_mask, y_pred[0])

fixed_mask_r=K.cast(fixed_mask_r, dtype='float32')
moving_mask_r=K.cast(moving_mask_r, dtype='float32')

loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.math.squared_difference(fixed_mask_r,moving_mask_r))

return loss
```

There is no trouble for me running the loss function by itself, however, when I put it into the network it outputs this error:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

How am I able to find the operator that does not have the gradient? And what are the possible ways to fix it?

Comment: `tf.where` obviously doesn't have gradient.

Comment: Thanks! What makes it obvious? I am relatively new to this so I have no idea.